# JQUERY UI: link to get ALWAYS the very last version of "jquery-ui.min.js"

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, libraries

Good morning everyone.

I know you all don't like this question, as it is a bad design software behaviour which can create common breaks to suposed functionality.
But right now, I'm just designing a PoC, and I need to run it up always with the last version of the very common third part libraries.

As I can go to jQuery Github site, and using **jsDelivr** + **SRIHash**, I can serve to my code the very last version of jquery (or any other library which gots the "inclusable" JS on it).

So, this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery-dist/master/dist/jquery.min.js

becomes this:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery/jquery-dist/dist/jquery.min.js

and finally:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery/jquery-dist/dist/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Upper LINK will always provide the very last Jquery version. No version specified at any point.

So, as said, this is usable for any kind of JS which mantains it's common library name on some folder and gets it's own versioning over itself, and not in some versions sub-folders.
Which is PRECISELY the problem Jquery-UI has. And even worst, because it doesn't have the proper **jquery-ui.min.js** on it, **which is the one I need**.

I have found third-people aproximations like this one:

https://github.com/components/jqueryui

But still it being the last version, it is an incorrect version of the library, as it has one little but important difference inside the code (an slash symbol on a RegExp), so it is not a reliable version of it.

I've tried with CDNs from Google and Microsoft. NPM, Composer, Bower... all of'em are versionated links, so you've to specify ".../1.12.1/..." in some point.

¿Ideas?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Just for you to know, [es.so] exists since 2015. Maybe you never heard of it but today you created a new usr there. :P  regards

Comment: Just by posting? Good to know. :)

Comment: Not sure how you did it but not just by posting... maybe miss click somewhere. Here are some banners about SOes.

Comment: I always navigate to http://code.jquery.com/ and gather the latest versions. I have not seen any CDN that offers what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice!
Found by myself. After searching like crazy, seems like NPM has a repository by jquery people (official, not third peoples), called "DIST", and it has what it have to have inside:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha384-PtTRqvDhycIBU6x1wwIqnbDo8adeWIWP3AHmnrvccafo35E7oIvW7HPXn2YimvWu" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

So this is it:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui-dist

Then via jsDelivr:

https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/jquery-ui-dist

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js

And then, SRI Hash it and it's over.

Nice!

---

**EDIT:**

Happens that NPM dist repository has the very exact problem has I've found before:

[image]
(left, min version from jquery UI cdn site. Right, min version from NPM jquery-ui-dist repository)

It seems that minified version on NPM hast the "back-slash" error on the RegExp selector too. While in the minified version of CDN from jquery UI website, hasn't. Seen the uncompressed version of the code from both sites (jquery oficial CDN and NPM repository) which are exactly the same (binary identicals), the back-slash is not in there too. So the minified version existing in some repositories (NPM included), are incorrect.

I even minified full version myself, and the RegExp do not get modified in any manner (so no back-slash added ever). Dont understand why this happens, but solution is going to be to include de uncompressed version of jquery UI, which is double the size, from ~200KB to 500KB aprox.